# How to remove UIImageView from another UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ipad

In touchesBegan method i added stampBrush Image to drawImage where both are UIImageView

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     stampBrush = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[PaintColor stampImages] objectAtIndex:[stamp_Default integerForKey:STAMP_TYPE]]];

            [stampBrush setFrame:CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, stampBrush.image.size.width,stampBrush.image.size.height)];
            [drawImage addSubview:stampBrush];

}
```

Now i am trying to remove one by one on removeStampBrush clicked!
which stampBrush need to remove from drawImage!

```
-(void)removeStampBrush:(UIButton *)sender{



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to remove the stamps in reverse order, I would extend UIImageView as follows:

YourImageView.h

```
@interface YourImageView : UIImageView {
    NSMutableArray *stamps;
}

- (void)addStamp:(UIImageView *)stamp;
- (void)removeLastStamp;

@end
```

YourImageView.m

```
#import "YourImageView.h"

@implementation YourImageView

-(void)dealloc {
    [stamps release];

    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)addStamp:(UIImageView *)stamp {
    if (stamps == nil) {
        stamps = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
    }

    [stamps addObject:stamp];
    [self addSubview:stamp];
}

- (void)removeLastStamp {
    if (stamps.count > 0) {
        UIImageView *stamp = [stamps lastObject];
        [stamp removeFromSuperview];

        [stamps removeLastObject];
    }
}

@end
```

Now from your touch event call `[drawImage addStamp:stampBrush]` and to remove the last one `[drawImage removeLastStamp]`

Answer (score 1):

```
if([stampBrush superView])
{
    [stampBrush removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: is that check "if" really needed? what if [stampBrush superView] is nil? i guess we could just call [stampBrush removeFromSuperView], it shouldn't give any error... ?

Comment: @The Saad!  I added three image when iam using[stampBrush removeFromSuperView];  the last image which added to drawImage is removed when i click it again its not able to remove!

Comment: even i check condtion if nill its bring same result!

Comment: How do you know which stampBrush to remove? Or do you always want to remove them in reverse order you added them?

Comment: @iTukker  Yes i want to remove them in reverse order !

Comment: @kiran the need of if is I jst put there to know that whether a view is added to a superview or not. and to remove the view from super view if and only if it was added to it. it will not null if it was added to it

Comment: @meronix you can use loop to check while till check if it is not bill